# Why is my iPhone X 4K video so grainy and crappy?

Tags: photo-editing, photography-basics, iphone

https://youtu.be/j41QKS16DSE

Sample video above. Please take a look. Recorded at 4K 30 FPS.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of low-light photography with a small sensor!

Comment: @fkraiem - I figured it was the low light. I only asked because I see other videos posted on YouTube from iPhones that are stunning quality.

Comment: [Say no to vertical videos!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bt9zSfinwFA)

Comment: While this is on topic here due to being the same reason as if you were shooting stills.  Please be aware there is also a [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) site for video related questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much of a light, so the ISO must be high.

Sidenote: Do not record in portrait mode. Don't you see how the black stripes on the side?